# All buttons are updating on single click. React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've added three buttons with loading icon, If I click on single button the rest of two buttons also shows loading status.

I guess i'm doing something wrong in the state.

Please check my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class LoadingBtn extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: false
    };

    clickFunction = () => {
        this.setState({
            loading: !this.state.loading
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.clickFunction}>
                    {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
                    {loading && <span>Joining app...</span>}
                    {!loading && <span>ALLOW</span>}
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.clickFunction}>
                    {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
                    {loading && <span>Joining app...</span>}
                    {!loading && <span>ALLOW</span>}
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.clickFunction}>
                    {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
                    {loading && <span>Joining app...</span>}
                    {!loading && <span>ALLOW</span>}
                </Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a single state value that you're updating on the click. All the buttons are linked to the same state value, so when you click on any of them all of them react to the new state.

What you need to do is change your function to take a unique value to represent each button on click, id or name perhaps.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class LoadingBtn extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: false
    };

    clickFunction = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            loading: e.id
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.state.loading;

        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                id = "uniqueGeneratedIDForEachButton1"
                onClick={(e) => this.clickFunction(e)}>
                    {loading === "uniqueGeneratedIDForEachButton1" ? 
                    <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i><span>Joining app...</span> : 
                    <span>ALLOW</span>}
                </Button>
                <Button
                id = "uniqueGeneratedIDForEachButton2"
                onClick={(e) => this.clickFunction(e)}>
                    {loading === "uniqueGeneratedIDForEachButton2" ? 
                    <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i><span>Joining app...</span> : 
                    <span>ALLOW</span>}
                </Button>
                <Button
                id = "uniqueGeneratedIDForEachButton3"
                onClick={(e) => this.clickFunction(e)}>
                    {loading === "uniqueGeneratedIDForEachButton3" ? 
                    <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i><span>Joining app...</span> : 
                    <span>ALLOW</span>}
                </Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Ultimatly i want to fetch app list from db, and each app will have one button. If i click on particular button , i just want to show loading on that button only. not on all buttons. Consider i have hunders of buttons.

Comment: @VijayT in that case a unique value generated for each button is the way to go. Pass that to the function and the state, compare the state to the value for that button to indicate loading. Set the state back to a null value when loading is done.

Comment: Hey, i'm following your suggestions.

so far , i passed the app value to onclick function.


Now stuck here... how to pass that value to the state and compare?

 <Button onClick={() => clickFunction(apps.id)}>
                    {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
                    {loading && <span>Joining app...</span>}
                    {!loading && <span>ALLOW</span>}
</Button>

Comment: @VijayT, I've edited to show the way I play it. Snippets don't like arrow functions in buttons unfortunately but it should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

thats because is only one loading variable. You must do:

```
state = {
    loadingA: false,
    loadingB: false,
    loadingC: false
};
```

and do the corresponding logic, OR BETTER:

Create a button component with is own state and use thrice in your main class.

Comment: Ultimatly i want to fetch app list from db, and each app will have one button. If i click on particular button , i just want to show loading on that button only. not on all buttons. Consider i have hunders of buttons.